# Select from one tables based on conditions in two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a database validation query that will check for non unique data in a table based of two different tables.
I have three tables described with data below.

**Customer can have n amounts of Invoices.**
**Customer and Invoice can have 1 subsidiary.**

### Data

Customertable

```
customerid.   1 | currencyid.  10
customerid.   2 | currencyid.  12
```

Invoicetable

```
invoiceid.  1|customerid.  1| currencyid.  10
invoiceid.  2|customerid.  1| currencyid.  10
invoiceid.  3|customerid.  1| currencyid.  12
invoiceid.  4|customerid.  2| currencyid.  12
invoiceid.  5|customerid.  2| currencyid.  12
```

Subsidiarytable

```
type.  customer| typeid. 1| subsidiaryid.   1
type.   invoice| typeid. 1| subsidiaryid.   1
type.   invoice| typeid. 2| subsidiaryid.   2
type.   invoice| typeid. 3| subsidiaryid.   2
type.  customer| typeid. 2| subsidiaryid.   2
type.   invoice| typeid. 4| subsidiaryid.   2
type.   invoice| typeid. 5| subsidiaryid.   2
```

### Example

Is there a way of writing a query that find if customer have connected invoices with non unique subsidiaries? I.e, the above data should return an error as the third subsidiary in the table have another subsidiaryid then the first two, the fourth one is ignored as it's connected to another currency.

### Expected result

The above query should return `customerid` 1 as it has different subsidiaries on the customer and one of the invoices..
Customerid 2 has matching subsidiaries on the customer and all of the invoices connected to it.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Expected result from the example is `customerid 1`as it has non unqiue subsidiaries

Comment: Sample table data should also include a customer not having non-unique subsidiaries.

Comment: Updated with more sample data

Comment: Step 1, write a query (SELECT) that returns customers and their subsidiaries. (Use `JOIN`.)

Answer (score 0):

To cross-reference two tables, a simple solution is to use multiple table references in the form of a comma separated list.

Once this is done you can compare the values as returned by `select...from` one row at a time.

To find any inconsistencies, first check that the `customer id` is the same, and then check if the `currency` is different.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table custcurr (cust int,curr int);
create table invcustcurr (inv int,cust int,curr int);

insert into custcurr values (1,10),(2,12);
insert into invcustcurr values (1,1,10),(2,1,10),(3,1,12),(4,2,12),(5,2,12);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select icc.inv,cc.* from custcurr cc,invcustcurr icc
where cc.cust=icc.cust and cc.curr<>icc.curr;
```

| inv | cust | curr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 10 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubWaQSGBtPsjCxgLrKoVYp/0)